# Why should I avoid instantiating a CollectionView directly?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, collectionviewsource

The [documentation of the CollectionView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview?view=netframework-4.7.2) says:

> You should not create objects of this class in your code. To create a collection view for a collection that only implements IEnumerable, create a CollectionViewSource object, add your collection to the Source property, and get the collection view from the View property.

In other words, I am supposed to write:

```
var cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
cvs.Source = myData.Where(d => someCondition(d));
var view = cvs.View;
```

instead of

```
var view = new CollectionView(myData.Where(d => someCondition(d));
```

However, the documention fails to explain *why* I should do that. Both options *seem* to work.

**What bad things will happen if I choose option 2 over option 1?**

Answer (score 2):

There are a few specializations of the `CollectionView` class, like for example `ListCollectionView`. Whenever you bind to some collection, there is a view automatically generated for you based on the type of the source collection. Instead of explicitly creating a `CollectionView` or a `CollectionViewSource`, you can get the default view of a collection by using the static `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` method:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myData);
```

It will return a `ListCollectionView` if `myData` implements `IList`.

It's perfectly fine to expose an `ICollectionView` from a view model if you perform the filtering or sorting in there. A `CollectionViewSource` is mainly used when you want to perform the filtering, sorting or grouping of a source collection in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Binding CollectionView may present problems down the road if you want to change the way your data is displayed.

From the CollectionViewSource documentation:

> Because a view does not change the underlying source collection, a source collection can have multiple views associated with it. By using views, you can display the same data in different ways. For example, you can use two views on a collection of Task objects to show tasks sorted by priority on one part of the page and grouped by area on another part of the page.

Binding directly to a single CollectionView limits the ways you can display your data.In short, CollectionViewSource plays nicer with your collections in XAML when binding.

Comment: "Binding directly to a single CollectionView limits the ways you can display your data."
What would prevent one from creating multiple CollectionViews around the same collection ?